# Xcode / Interface Builder, use defines / constants for object tags

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is there any "approved" way to use a define / constant in the IB for tags for objects that can also be reference in code? Yes or no please.  If Yes example please.

Comment: Nope nothing official. Making  constants and ensuring the link between your code and IB are up to date seems like the sensible thing to be doing. There are some tools out there that attempt to make this task easier but essentially your on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**.

(As per your question, you only asked yes or no, and example only on yes.)

There is not any "approved" way to use a define / constant in the IB for tags for objects that can also be reference in code.